# When to use antPattern '/api/**' over '/api' in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have override the configure method of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class as:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin();
}
```

I have APIs as /admin, /admin/user, /admin/user/test. When i login as admin i can access all the three URLs. I just wanted to know the difference between '/admin/**' and '/admin',

Answer (score 1):

In case of /api/**, hasRole(...) will be authorized to all the requests that starts with the pattern /api. 
And in case of /api, hasRole(...) will be authorized to only one request i.e. /api

In the above question only the '/admin' request is authorized to 'ADMIN' role. We can also access the other URLs because other URLs just need to be authenticated ignoring the role. We can also access the '/admin/user' or '/admin/user/test' while logging with user. If we have used antPattern as '/admin/**', then we won't be able to access those APIs through the session of user.

I am new to Spring Security and i was about to post the question but after spending some time, i came to know a little about it, so i also included my understanding for suggestions.